# how to comment out the first occurrence with sed

Tags: linux, replace, sed, comments

I’m trying to comment out a line in a config file with sed and have an issue.

I am using `sed –i '/GV()/s/^/#/' filename`

and it works, but it comments out all occurrences of `GV()` in the file. I only want to comment out the first occurrence.

Any idea how I can do this with sed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -i '/GV()/{s/.*/#&/;:A;n;bA}' file
```

Comment: sed -i '/GV()/{s/.*/#&/;:A;n;bA}' Worked perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -e '1,/GV()/s/GV()/#GV()/' filename
```

Comment: Assuming `GV()` is not on the 1st line. Very good simple solution. Same enhanced `sed '1,/GV()/ s//#&/' YourFile`

Answer (score 0):

For this problem, awk is a natural tool.  Consider this test file:

```
$ cat file
one
GV()
GV()
```

Then, using awk:

```
$ awk '/GV()/ && !f {print "#"$0; f=1; next} 1' file
one
#GV()
GV()
```

The above comments out a line containing `GV()` only if no such line has been seen before.  The variable `f` keeps track of whether `GV()` has been seen before.

#### How it works

- `/GV()/ && !f {print "#"$0; f=1; next}`

  `/GV()/ && !f` is a condition: the statements which follow in braces, `{...}`, are only executed if the condition is true.  It is true only if the line contains `GV()` and if `f` is false, meaning that we haven't seen such a line before.  In that case, we (a) comment out the line, `print "#"$0`, (b) set `f` to true: `f=1`, and (c) skip the rest of the commands and start over on the `next` line.
- `1`

  This awk's cryptic shorthand for print the line.